# Searching for an equal string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not sure how to word the question title.

```python
a = "Alpha";
b = "Bravo";
c = "Charlie";

fn = input("What is your first name: ")

for fletter in fn.split():
    fl = fletter[0]
```

The code above gets the first letter entered. The goal is to then get the first letter to possible check in a while loop to see if the value of fl = one of the starting strings. Is that possible to do? Tips on where to begin?

Comment: Do you mean comparing the string to the variable name?

Comment: Exactly @Jerrybibo

Comment: I've posted an answer. @Gramms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution 1 [Using a dictionary]

Also makes things much simpler.

In this case, instead of defining separate variables for each string, you store them in a dictionary. So for example, instead of this:

```
a = "Alpha"
b = "Bravo"
c = "Charlie"
```

You would have this:

```
letterwords = {"a":"Alpha", "b":"Bravo", "c":"Charlie"}
```

This works very similarly to a list, however instead of *indexing* the dictionary you would reference to separate objects inside a dictionary according to its *key*. So if the dictionary `letterwords` is defined as above, you would reference to the string `Alpha` by calling `letterwords["a"]`. Therefore, in this case, the code would look something like this:

```
letterwords = {"a":"Alpha", "b":"Bravo", "c":"Charlie"}
fn = input("Please enter your first name: ")
try:
    letterwords[fn[0]]
except KeyError:
    print("There is no matching variable with that letter in the database.")
```

## Solution 2 [Using the eval() function]

*Not recommended.*

This is perfectly possible, with the eval function. **However, you should be aware that this is a quite dangerous function to run, as malicious users can use this to control the console. (Especially if you imported os.)** However, it should get you over the hump for now. Here's the code:

```
a = "Alpha"
b = "Bravo"
c = "Charlie"
fl = input("Please enter your first name: ")
try:
    compared = eval(fl[0])
except NameError:
    print("Your first name's first letter does not match any strings in the database.")
```

More information on the eval() function here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval

Hope this helped!

Comment: mmm, I think that you mean `eval(fl[0])`

Comment: Oh yeah. @Copperfield Fixing the answer now.

Comment: used like this there is no risk in eval, because as far I now nobody can hack anything with just a character, still the dictionary one is the better one

Comment: @Copperfield Putting the warning there because I got yelled at for posting an answer with eval() without warning about what it could do. You never know.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you @Jerrybibo